# Getting a file from my non-syncing Mac to my iPad?

Tags: file-transfer

My professor posted a reading assignment via PDF, and my iPad isn't rendering the website he set up so I can't download the PDF to iBooks.

I have my MacBook with me, but it's not the main computer to which I sync all my devices (which is my mini at home). I can email the file to myself, but that would only work for files below 20mb, which if I need to read a whole book, would be too much to email.

Is there another way to get the file to my iPad for reading without having to go all the way home to sync my iPad to my mini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Dropbox might be your best bet with the large files. There is an app available for iPad so you can view the files on there.

Comment: If Dropbox will work, then I'm guessing Google Drive would also work. I didn't think of those options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any app that uses iTunes File Sharing (e.g. FileApp) will let you add/remove files without having to be the there-can-be-only-one syncing computer.

You just pop over to the Apps tab on your device in iTunes and scroll down. You'll see e.g. FileApp in the list and you can just drag your file over to the list and it will be transferred.